# Linker Error in DLib

Tags: dlib

I'm getting the following linker error. How can I solve it?

```
d:\ram\software\dlib latest 22nd aug\dlib-master\dlib\array2d\../algs.h(286): error C2144: syntax error : 'bool' should be preceded by ';' [D:\Ram\Software\Dlib latest
 22nd Aug\dlib-master\examples\build\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
d:\ram\software\dlib latest 22nd aug\dlib-master\dlib\array2d\../algs.h(287): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 [D:\Ram\Software\Dlib latest 22nd Aug\dlib-master\examples\build\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
d:\ram\software\dlib latest 22nd aug\dlib-master\dlib\array2d\../algs.h(287): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' [D:\Ram\Software\Dlib latest 22nd Aug\
dlib-master\examples\build\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
d:\ram\software\dlib latest 22nd aug\dlib-master\dlib\array2d\../algs.h(289): error C2803: 'operator >' must have at least one formal parameter of class type [D:\Ram\S
oftware\Dlib latest 22nd Aug\dlib-master\examples\build\dlib_build\dlib.vcxproj]
```

Comment: what is the compiler you are using?

Comment: Please also post the code that elicits the problem.

Comment: this problem may occur with VS 2013 and dlib v.19.2. solutions: update to VS 2013 up5, use VS2015 or use dlib v19.1